# VBA error for a list box code

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to correct a VBA error for a code I created to show list box values into Excel. Can anybody help please?

```
Dim lbValue As Long
 lbValue = Summary.ListBoxes("BusinessOwnerListBox").Value

 Dim lbtext As String
 With Summary.ListBoxes("BusinessOwnerListBox").ControlFormat
    lbtext = .List(.Value)
 End With
```

List is multi select single and items are added by using Add Item. The items are showing in the form but the list value chosen does not carry into the spread sheet on running the code.

Full Code

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

 Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click()

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub InitialTermListBox_Click()

End Sub


Private Sub OKButton_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Summary active
 Summary.Activate

 'Determine emptyRow
 emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
 Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = SupplierNameTextBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = GeneralDescriptionTextBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = DepartmentListBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ContractStartDateTextBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = InitialTermListBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = RenewalTermListBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = PaymentTermsListBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = SelectionMechanismListBox.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = ValueOfContractTextBox.Value

 Dim lbtext As Variant
 lbtext = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value
 Worksheets("Summary").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = lbtext


If SignedContractCheckBox.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value =        SignedContractCheckBox.Caption

End Sub


Private Sub PaymentTermsListBox_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub RenewalTermListBox_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectionMechanismListBox_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

 End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty SupplierNameTextBox
 SupplierNameTextBox.Value = ""

'Uncheck SignedContractCheckBox
 SignedContractCheckBox.Value = False

'Empty GeneralDescriptionTextBox
 GeneralDescriptionTextBox.Value = ""

 'Empty BusinessOwnerListBox
 BusinessOwnerListBox.Clear

 'Fill BusinessOwnerListBox
With BusinessOwnerListBox
    .AddItem ""
    .AddItem "Alison Gillies"
    .AddItem "Bernard Hunwick"
    .AddItem "Jon Williams"
    .AddItem "Laurent Sylvestre"
    .AddItem "Leeann McCallum"
    .AddItem "Sue Lowe"
End With

 'Empty DepartmentListBox
 DepartmentListBox.Clear

'Fill DepartmentListBox
 With DepartmentListBox
 .AddItem ""
 .AddItem "Buildings"
 .AddItem "Corporate Services"
 .AddItem "ICT"
 .AddItem "People & Culture"
 .AddItem "Transport & Logistics"
 End With

'Empty ContractStartDateTextBox
  ContractStartDateTextBox.Value = ""

 'Empty InitialTermListBox
  InitialTermListBox.Clear

 'Fill InitialTermListBox
 With InitialTermListBox
 .AddItem ""
 .AddItem "6"
 .AddItem "12"
 .AddItem "18"
 .AddItem "24"
 .AddItem "36"
End With

 'Empty RenewalTermListBox
  RenewalTermListBox.Clear

 'Fill RenewalTermListBox
  With RenewalTermListBox
 .AddItem ""
 .AddItem "6"
 .AddItem "12"
 .AddItem "18"
 .AddItem "24"
 .AddItem "36"
 End With

'Empty PaymentTermsListBox
 PaymentTermsListBox.Clear

'Fill PaymentTermsListBox
 With PaymentTermsListBox
 .AddItem ""
 .AddItem "7 days"
 .AddItem "30 days"
 .AddItem "20th month"
 .AddItem "Quarterly"
 .AddItem "Annual"
 End With

'Empty SelectionMechanismListBox
 SelectionMechanismListBox.Clear

'Fill SelectionMechanismListBox
 With SelectionMechanismListBox
 .AddItem ""
 .AddItem "RolledContract"
 .AddItem "RFP"
 .AddItem "RFQ"
 .AddItem "3 Quotes"
 .AddItem "2 Quote"
 .AddItem "Business Selection"
 End With

'Empty ValueOfContractTextBox
  ValueOfContractTextBox.Value = ""


 'Set Focus on SupplierNameTextBox
  SupplierNameTextBox.SetFocus


 End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly get rid of `.ControlFormat`?

Comment: `lbtext = .List(.Value)` all this does is to set the value of a string variable ?

Comment: I'm confused by the statement "List is multi select single".  Is it multiple selection, or single selection?  (But I very rarely [i.e. never?] use listboxes in Excel itself, so perhaps "multi select single" is really a thing and I just don't know what I am talking about.)

Comment: Doesn't work after getting rid of .ControlFormat. It is single selection. property box in vba refers to single selection as 0-fmMultiselectsingle

Comment: Form displays the list that I have added manually by add item but just doesn't carry over the value into the spreadsheet. If somebody has a formula for list box value to carry over value into spreadsheet, happy to use that instead of trying to fix mine.

Comment: Listbox is on a UserForm. Error is on                                                                                                               lbvalue = Summary.ListBoxes("BusinessOwnerListBox").Value             Runtime error 1004 Method ListBoxes failed

Comment: Is this code in the code module of the `Summary` Form?  If so, why don't you just use `lbtext = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value`?

Comment: Yes code is in the code module of the Summary Form

Comment: Or, if you want to put it into a worksheet somewhere, perhaps `Worksheets("sheet_I _want_to_update").Range("B4").Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value`

Comment: Tried that. Now I am getting an invalid use of null error on the                  lbtext = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value  line

Comment: Has the user selected a value from the listbox?  (You should test that they have selected something before attempting to use what they selected.) (But you wouldn't have to test if you write straight to the worksheet - the cell will accept a Null as a value.)

Comment: have tried using the form after selecting a value or writing straight to the worksheet. The form has other controls and data from textbox and checkbox comes through. Data from list box shows in the form on the spreadsheet but does not come through with either of the codes so far. No error message shoes with the new code by the value of the list box option does not come through. Cannot paste the full code into the comments section due to word count or would have. Perhaps that would have helped.

Comment: Don't paste code into comments - [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46637179/edit) the relevant code into the question.  (It's the question that is being answered, not the comments, so the question should contain all the information necessary to allow someone to answer.)  And the "in the form on the spreadsheet" bit in your last comment is making me worried - there are Forms and there are Worksheets, but I'm not sure what you mean by "form on the spreadsheet" - it is making me think that this is a Listbox in the worksheet rather than on a Form.

Comment: `Summary.Activate` implies that `Summary` is your worksheet's `CodeName`.  Is its `Name` also `"Summary"`?

Comment: Yes it is .....

Comment: You should be able to use identical style code to your other listboxes - i.e. `Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value`.  I don't like unqualified `Cells` references, but you have definitely done the `Summary.Activate`, so `Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value` will be the same as `Summary.Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value` will be the same as `Worksheets("Summary").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value` (providing the user doesn't activate some other sheet while the code is running)

Comment: Except that code does not work for any list box values including the businessowner one that I have tried

Comment: I cut your code down so that it had one CheckBox, one TextBox, one ListBox, and the OKButton and ClearButton, and the code works for me using `Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value`.

Comment: strange, mine still does not write to the worksheet. I will try copying it into a different file and see if it works

Comment: FWIW - I just saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46654206/6535336) (which has now been deleted so you won't be able to see it until you get another 9,999 rep) which was having the same issue as you.  Once I suggested that they check that the ListBox was set to fmMultiSelectSingle, the question was deleted very quickly - I assume that resolved their issue.  So check that all your listboxes are really set to single-selection and that one isn't accidentally set to multi-selection.

Comment: Thanks, it was single select but I ended up replacing list boxes with combo boxes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming code is in the code module of the form)*

To write directly from the Form to the worksheet:

```
Worksheets("some_sheet_name").Range("K9").Value = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value
```

---

To place the value selected into a variable and then write to the worksheet

```
Dim lbtext As String
'String variables can't store "Null" so need to check
If IsNull(BusinessOwnerListBox.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Select something!!"
    Exit Sub
End If
lbtext = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value
Worksheets("some_sheet_name").Range("K9").Value = lbtext
```

or

```
Dim lbtext As Variant
lbtext = BusinessOwnerListBox.Value
Worksheets("some_sheet_name").Range("K9").Value = lbtext
```